# Parsing ALL Highcharts Options from JSON

Tags: highcharts

I am currently wanting to specify all Highcharts chart options via a JSON file. I've seen plenty of examples on how to pull just the data series from JSON and understand that.

Here is an example of some chart options that I would like to convert to JSON

```
    var optionsChart2 = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Year End Rating: Distribution'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Ineffective',
            'Inconsistent',
            'Proficient',
            'Advanced',
            'Exceptional'
        ]
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Percentage'
        }
    },          
    series: [{data: 25,50,65,32,78}]
};
```

What is the best JSON format for that (for the purpose of pulling in via AJAX and then parsing back into options)?

I've seen the following code for parsing just the data:

```
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
```

How would I then use the new version of the JSON file (as above)?

I'm sorry if this is too vague. I'm relatively new to this and need some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it should be valid json, not valid javascript.
So strip the var and start immediately with the opening brace, remove the ; at the end and add double quotes around each property name.

So it looks like this:

```
{
    "chart" : { ...
    ...
}
```

Then do the same as your example, just pass the response as is to the HC constructor:

```
$.getJSON( 'options.json', function( options ) {
    new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I just had to add double-quotes around the strings to make it valid JSON. Thanks!